# PHP 1 of the 2 conditions is false, yet it marks as true

Tags: php

Currently losing it.
I have a page that has a condition that checks if a user is an Admin or Reparateur (Repair guys, translated)

When you login, the goal is to make sure that an admin user is only able to login from the $admin_ip thats been entered.

This piece of code is before the statements:

```
    $admin_ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.180";
    $login_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Later, the conditions checks it:

```
    if ($functie == "Admin" or "Reperateur" AND $login_ip == $admin_ip) {
         return true;
    } else if ($login_ip != $admin_ip AND $functie == "Admin" or "Reperateur") {
         return false;
    } else {
         return true;
    }
```

Debugging shows the statement should be false:

Debugging screenshot:

[image]

Am I just not seeing it or missing something?

Comment: The `or` check is invalid. Should be: `if (($functie == "Admin" or $functie == "Reperateur") AND ...` same in the next else if too.

Comment: please explain better your goal, I can not understand.

Comment: Hi @PaulT. i've just tried what you said, worked great. Thank you, new in PHP so this helps me out understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @PaulT. said:

The `or` check is invalid. Should be: `if (($functie == "Admin" or $functie == "Reperateur") AND ...` same in the next else if too.

So, the condition is fixed with the following:

```
  if (($functie == "Admin" or $functie == "Reperateur") AND $login_ip == $admin_ip) {
       return true;
  } else if (($functie == "Admin" or $functie == "Reperateur") AND $login_ip != $admin_ip) {
       return false;
  } else {
       return true;
  }
```